# Press a key in a batch script with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script in python that execute a batch program that need press two or three times the "d" key and after the "q" key.

I tried this but without solution:

```
import os
import keyboard
import time
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

os.system('"C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Software/xxx.exe 192.168.0.15"')
time.sleep(5)

keyboard = Controller()
keyd = "d"
keyq = "q"

keyboard.press(keyd)
keyboard.release(keyd)
time.sleep(3)
keyboard.press(keyq)
keyboard.release(keyq)
```

Only open the console but the script don't press the keys, but if you press with the keyboard the program works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the `subprocess` module.

**Example:**

`subprocess-test.py`

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["python", "input-app.py"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

p.stdin.write("Hello\n".encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
p.stdin.write("World\n".encode(encoding='UTF-8'))
```

`input-app.py`

```
input1 = input("Input 1: ")
input2 = input("Input 2: ")

print(input1, input2)
```

See more information here:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/3684694/42659

Sorry, I won't be able to help more as I only have a short lunch break. I hope this already does help though or points you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can use: `pyautogui` for pressing code as simply as:

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.press('d')
```

Your case can be handled as follows:

```
import os
import pyautogui
import time

os.system('"C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Software/xxx.exe 192.168.0.15"')
time.sleep(5)

keyd = "d"
keyq = "q"

pyautogui.press(keyd)
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.press(keyq)
```

If pressing keys don't work, you may try to enter exact strings as well:

```
import os
import pyautogui
import time

os.system('"C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Software/xxx.exe 192.168.0.15"')
time.sleep(5)

keyd = "d"
keyq = "q"

pyautogui.write(keyd)
time.sleep(3)
pyautogui.write(keyq)
```

Comment: I tried this solution, but still not work. You can pulse in the keyboard the D key and works fine and show the output, but I think Python cannot press keys when execute ".exe" files.

Comment: Try pyautogui.write() instead